# How to use insert and update in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

How to use the insert and update in hibernate to change avoid updating a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use both types.But in the second case retrieval is easy.You can get the object simply.
But in the first case you need to pass the id to database to get the object.

Otherwise you can use both options one for insert and one for retrieval .When inserting use

```
developerObj.setDevID(12);
```

and set `insertable = false and updatable = false`

When you retrieve use `project.developer.devId`

Comment: but the problem is that if I create a new object hibernate will create a new record in database with null values for all the fields except id (which is 12) but I do not want it to create the object because object is already created.

Comment: then use insertable = false and updatable = false to avoid multiple insertins

Comment: can u post that statement from entity

Comment: @JackRamzi @JoinColumn(name="column_name", updatable = false, insertable = false)

Comment: @JackRamzi did you understand now

Comment: so if I use it I need to use save on the object to be saved otherwise it will be ignored right?

Comment: if yo set object also it will not save that

Comment: So how about if I want to insert both (create developer first) and the create the object of its project?

Comment: it follow the second approach

Comment: I do not get you let me try it :D

Comment: It runs into following error Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: I think it is because I am trying to set ID of developer which is defined as generatevalue